# Accessing form's button field

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a button on my form, but I am unable to access it from my code. My code (from `Program.cs`):

```cs
Form1.button1.Text = "Button text"
```

I cannot access it due to it's protection level. What shall I do to change this field protection level or something?

Comment: Change button1 protection level or create a public helper method (something like `SetTextForButton1(String newText)`)?

Comment: Bind the Text Property of the button to a common datasource and change the datasource.

Comment: Don't simply write `CLOSED` in the title of your question. Accept an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How to bind the text of a winforms button to a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322484/c-how-to-bind-the-text-of-a-winforms-button-to-a-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the properties window you can change the privacy of the components. You need to change the button privacy to public.

--EDIT
What fildor wrote is a better aproach

Comment: Thank you.. Design -> Modifiers. Sorry me :D

Comment: That's a rather bad idea. Use Databinding instead!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the modifier of an object is a bad idea.
Better would  be to create a public property on Form1, for example `Button1Text` and call that in stead of accesing a private object.

```
public string Button1Text
{  
   get { return Button1.Text; }
   set {Button1.Text = value; }
}
```

then call it like this

```
form1.Button1Text = "I am a button"
```

Make sure that form1 is the created instance for your form, not the class name !